# SwiftUI Push multiple View with button clicked in embedded subviews

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, swiftui, combine

I am scratching my head since two days, but the new SwiftUI navigation part is kind of weird to me.

Short description of my issue:
I have a ViewA, it contains 3 subviews (Subview1,Subview2,Subview3). In each of them I have 2 or 3 buttons (Subview1ButtonA, Subview1ButtonB, Subview1ButtonC).
I wanna push different view depending on which button is tapped.
Before, we needed to be in the ViewA to be able to push a view by using a callback, notifications, whatever to notify ViewA that we want to push a ViewB for example.
Here, with SwiftUI, I don't understand at all what it expect us to do with `NavigationLink`.

Here's is my sample code for demonstrate my use case.

```
// MainView.swift

final class State: ObservableObject {
    // Close allow me to close my ViewA, it is a modal and I have a button X integrated
    // in Subview1ButtonA
    @Published var closePressed: Bool = false
    @Published var isView2Presented: Bool = false
}

struct ViewA: View {
    @ObservedObject var state = State()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(content: {
                 NavigationLink(destination: View2(isPresented: self.$state.isView2Presented),
                                isActive: self.$state.isView2Presented) {
                                ViewB(closePressed: self.$state.closePressed,
                                      view2Pressed: self.$state.isView2Presented)
                 }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

If I have a third button in ViewB how does it work since it is only one `NavigationLink` here..?
It is really confusing to me to be honest.

Thank you for any further help!

Edit:

I have a MainView, I have a couple subview in this MainView (lets say block of view pulled together to form the MainView) In this blocks, I have a couple buttons, and each button needs to open a different View. I am not sure to understand how to implement my navigation stuff here.

Comment: Not sure I understood the problem, would you elaborate more?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added an edit in my post, does it help to understand a little bit better?

Comment: Do I have to implement the `NavigationLink` independently in each Subviews?

I mean, with UIKit, you would create a delegate in your subview to track the button click for example. How do you do that in SwiftUI, it seems to be so hardcore to do something so simple.